# Adding grunt output directory to ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, gruntjs

I am creating a javascript webApp and i deploy it using GruntJS. this web app will be deployed in an ASP.NET MVC Web Service. I want to add the dist folder (and any files created by grunt inside the folder) programmatically inside the visual studio project, so when I build and deploy the web service I can navigate to this folder. Hope I was clear!

Comment: Here is a good start: http://joeriks.com/2013/08/06/can-i-benefit-from-grunt-for-my-visual-studio-based-web-development/

Comment: Thanks! seems promising

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Grunt is completely independent of IDEs and texteditors and is a really helpful tool for all kinds of web development in any editor.

Grunt is described as “a node based javascript task runner with which you can automate tasks like minification, compilation, unit testing, linting and more”. You can use it for example when you do not like to be dependent on an asp.net web server doing minification and bundling for you, or you simply like to be able to use tools that are not (yet) supported by the asp.net/Visual Studio ecosystem.

Here is all you need: http://joeriks.com/2013/08/06/can-i-benefit-from-grunt-for-my-visual-studio-based-web-development/

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link is very good, but it doesn't address my problem. The problem is that the generated files are not added automatically inside the Visual Studio project, but I have to add them manually

Answer (score 1):

Try to tweak WebDeploy settings in your MSBuild file (*.csproj?) so it would include files from the `dist` folder into your web application during publishing.

The following tutorial should be a good starting point how to do it:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files

Also check [ASP.NET Solution Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/359f4304-57d7-4178-9cab-165e2090dce2) on Visual Studio Gallery